# Using indexes to fill mean values in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

[image: Sample Data]

Trying to populate the mean values in a dataframe having NaN values. Need to populate the  dataframe  only for certain rows and not all rows.

Sample Data set

```
   A    b     c    
0 100   52    555
1 25   144    552
2 NaN  555    555
3 323  NaN    785
4 515  551    125
5 741  471    Nan
6 111  Nan    Nan
```

Here I need to fill values only for rows numbered 5 and 6 with the mean of  their respective columns and should ignore rows 3 and 4.

Comment: How do you decide which rows you need to update?

Comment: yes that's my question.. i need to update rows 5 and 6

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `fillna()` function on a dataframe slice

```
df.iloc[5:7].fillna(mean, inplace=True)
```